# Three Mutually Non-commuting Dynamic Variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

On the usual quantum-mechanical Hilbert space, the operators **q** and **p** commute to a constant:  [**q**,**p**]=*i*.

I'm looking for an elementary example of some Hilbert space for which 3 operators, **r**, **q**, and **p**, commute as follows:  [**q**,**p**]=*i*, [**p**,**r**]=*i*, and [**r**,**q**]=*i*.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $x-p_y$, $y-p_z$, and $z-p_x$. (One might have to scale each term with appropriate dimensionful constants to make the 3 operators of definite dimension.)

Comment: Thank you.  What a cunning scheme.  How should I cite it?

Comment: Feel free to use it :)

Comment: The hint from Qmechanic extends several ways: